# 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, django

I'm following a bit outdated tutorialand when testing a GET request which expecting to get all user list I get an error:

```
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'append'
```

below is UserProfile model.

```
 class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length = 128)
    comment = models.TextField()
    country = models.CharField(max_length = 128, blank = True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length = 128, blank = True)
    ignores = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name = 'ignore_set', blank = True, null = True)

    def serialize(self):
        data = {
        'user':self.user_id,
        'username':self.user.username,
        'nickname':self.nickname,
        'comment':self.comment,
        'country':self.country,
        'url':self.url,
        'ignores':[],
        }
        return data
```

below is the view.py (please refer **api/user/list** )

```
def user_view(request, method):
    # api/user/create: api that creating new account.
    if method == 'create' and request.method == 'POST':
        ...
    #api/user/update: api that update user's oldpassword with new one
    elif method == 'update' and request.method == 'POST':
        ...
    elif method == 'list':
        users = UserProfile.objects.all()
        return toJSON(serial(users))
    else:
        return toJSON({'status':'bad request'},400)
```

I guess below functions for serializing are root of issue.. but not sure how to fix it..

```
def serial(objs):
    serialized = []
    for obj in objs:
        objs.append(obj.serialize())
    return serialized

def toJSON(objs, status=200):
    j = json.dumps(objs, ensure_ascii=False)
    return HttpResponse(j, status=status, content_type='application/json; charset=utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your serial function is appending to the wrong thing (`objs` rather than `serialized`)

```
def serial(objs):
    serialized = []
    for obj in objs:
        objs.append(obj.serialize())
    return serialized
```

should be

```
def serial(objs):
    serialized = []
    for obj in objs:
        serialized.append(obj.serialize())
    return serialized
```

Comment: Note: You might want to find a better tutorial (djangos official is pretty good), and then perhaps take a look at django rest framework

Comment: it's indeed a basic mistake.. yes I would definitely take django official tutorial, much appreciated for your help.